# split ul list by li class name with jQuery

Tags: list, split

I have this ul li list

```
<div class="item">
<ul>
<li class="a">A1</li>
<li class="a">A2</li>
<li class="a">A3</li>
<li class="b">B1</li>
<li class="b">B2</li>
<li class="b">B3</li>
<li class="c">C1</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to split the ul element after every last class of li 
inseparrate list

How can i split into this with jQuery

```
<div class="item">
<ul>
<li class="a">A1</li>
<li class="a">A2</li>
<li class="a">A3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="item">
<ul>
<li class="b">B1</li>
<li class="b">B2</li>
<li class="b">B3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="item">
<ul>
<li class="c">C1</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any help please
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use [underscore's groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy), then remove all the html, and reinsert with your new structure.

```
var items = _.groupBy($('.item ul > li'), function(li) { return $(li).prop('class'); });
for(className in items) {
  var lis = items[className];
  var div = $('<div class="item"></div>');
  var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
  $(lis).each(function(i,e) {
    ul.append($(e));
  });
  div.append(ul);
  $('#container').append(div);
};
```

Here's a jsfiddle. Not the best implementation, but it should get you close enough! http://jsfiddle.net/p93r1rv4/

Comment: This working just fine but how can be removed the first empty ul from the split?

Comment: Hmm.. You could do something like `$('#container').html(''); $('#container').append(div);` That would wipe out the current html, then add in the new html.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming HTML elements at the bottom. You can use `jQuery.each` to prepend elements and do:

```
$.each( $("ul.old li.a"), function( k, val) {
    $("#ul_a").prepend('<li class="a">' + val.innerHTML + '</li>');
});

$.each( $("ul.old li.b"), function( k, val) {
    $("#ul_b").prepend('<li class="b">' + val.innerHTML + '</li>');
});

$.each( $("ul.old li.c"), function( k, val) {
    $("#ul_c").prepend('<li class="c">' + val.innerHTML + '</li>');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
<ul class="old">
<li class="a">A1</li>
<li class="a">A2</li>
<li class="a">A3</li>
<li class="b">B1</li>
<li class="b">B2</li>
<li class="b">B3</li>
<li class="c">C1</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="item">
    New Lists: <br/>
    <ul id='ul_a'> </ul>
    <ul id='ul_b'> </ul>
    <ul id='ul_c'> </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice solution too I think that .append() would be better becouse the order of li will be inverted and  $("ul.old ").remove();  at the end would remove the old <ul>